# In bash, either exit script without exiting the shell or export/set variables from within subshell

Tags: bash, shell

I have a function that runs a set of scripts that set variables, functions, and aliases in the current shell.

```bash
reloadVariablesFromScript() {
  for script in "${scripts[@]}"; do
    . "$script"
  done
}
```

If one of the scripts has an error, I want to exit the script and then exit the function, but not to kill the shell.

```bash
reloadVariablesFromScript() {
  for script in "${scripts[@]}"; do
    {(
      set -e
      . "$script"
    )}
    if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
      >&2 echo $script failed.  Skipping remaining scripts.
      return 1
    fi
  done
}
```

This would do what I want except it doesn't set the variables in the script whether the script succeeds or fails.

Without the subshell, `set -e` causes the whole shell to exit, which is undesirable.

Is there a way I can either prevent the called script from continuing on an error without killing the shell or else set/export variables, aliases, and functions from within a subshell?

The following script simulates my problem:

```bash
test() {
  {(
    set -e

    export foo=bar
    false
    echo Should not have gotten here!
    export bar=baz
  )}

  local errorCode=$?

  echo foo="'$foo'".  It should equal 'bar'.
  echo bar="'$bar'".  It should not be set.

  if [[ $errorCode -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo Script failed correctly.  Exiting function.
    return 1
  fi

  echo Should not have gotten here!
}

test
```

If worst comes to worse, since these scripts don't actually edit the filesystem, I can run each script in a subshell, check the exit code, and if it succeeds, run it outside of a subshell.

Comment: The script either runs on the current shell or not. If you don't want your shell to exit, don't use `set -e`.

Comment: Would it be okay to have only the environment variables from scripts that succeeed, and the failed scripts do not set them?

Comment: @MarcSances Yes, that would actually be ideal.  Although, it must include aliases and functions.

Comment: That "must include aliases and functions" detail is critical -- I had a half-written answer that wouldn't have included that. Functions can be exported to the environment, but aliases cannot; it's an important requirement to call out explicitly.

Comment: @alecxs, ...if the user _doesn't_ source the script, they won't have its functions/variables/aliases/etc. in their parent environment if it succeeds, which is what they're explicitly trying to accomplish.

Comment: @MarcSances Your answer might have worked with an added `alias >> .env`.  The other thing I need to do, then, would be to pass in the environment variables from the current shell, since I don't want global variables being overwritten if they're not defined explicitly in the script.

Comment: But functions would not be declared since you're running in a subshell.

Comment: @MarcSances `declare -f >> .env` ;)

Comment: Oh, cool, then go ahead with files?

Comment: Only if I can inject the outer shell's environment into the inner one.  I suppose I could do that by creating a temporary file of the outer shell's environment and loading it in the inner shell's.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to interrupt dot command without some very ugly hack.

Comment: That's exactly what I had tried to do in an answer (save to a temporary file), but just for environment variables, then deleted it since you needed more.

Comment: Oh, it looks like I was mistaken.  Subshells automatically inherit the environment of the parent shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that [`set -e` has a number of surprising behaviors](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) -- relying on it is not universally considered a good idea. That caveat being give, though: We can shuffle environment variables, aliases, and shell functions out as text:

```
envTest() {
  local errorCode newVars
  newVars=$(
    set -e

    {
      export foo=bar
      false
      echo Should not have gotten here!
      export bar=baz
    } >&2

    # print generate code which, when eval'd, recreates our functions and variables
    declare -p | egrep -v '^declare -[^[:space:]]*r'
    declare -f
    alias -p
  ); errorCode=$?
  if (( errorCode == 0 )); then
    eval "$newVars"
  fi
 
  printf 'foo=%q. It should equal %q\n' "$foo" "bar"
  printf 'bar=%q. It should not be set.\n' "$bar"
 
  if [[ $errorCode -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo 'Script failed correctly.  Exiting function.'
    return 1
  fi
 
  echo 'Should not have gotten here!'
}
 
envTest
```

Note that this code only evaluates *either* `export` should the entire script segment succeed; the question text and comments appear to indicate that this is acceptable if not desired.

Comment: I'm getting some errors `BASH_ARGC: variable may not be assigned value`, and the same for `BASH_ARGV`, `BASH_LINENO`, and `BASH_SOURCE`, as well as `syntax error near unexpected token '('`.  I'm not sure which line causes that last error.  If it matters, I'm using Git Bash in Windows.

Comment: Hmm. In bash 5.0.16 writing to those is allowed -- but you can always modify the `egrep` to take them out (as its purpose is already eliminating read-only variables from the set we pass from child to parent).